# Issues with hook_user and redirecting logout in Drupal

Tags: drupal, redirect, module, logout

Okay so I'm trying to customize a different logout destination other than the frontpage with the following module:

```
function mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {

    case 'logout':

        $_REQUEST['destination'] = 'user';

      break;

    default:

      break;
  }
}
```

It would be nice if I could redirect users on my site back to the login form after they logout, but this doesn't seem to work.  I tried a fresh install and can't seem to get it working there either.

Am I missing something here?

Edit:

I seem to be able to place a case for changing the login and it works, but the logout doesn't seem to fire in the same way, even without a case for login:

```
function mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  global $user;
  switch ($op) {

    case 'logout':

        drupal_goto('user');

      break;
    case 'login':

        $dest  = $arr[0];
        $_REQUEST['destination'] = $dest;

      break;

    default:

      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may add:

```
unset($edit['destination']);
```

After:

```
$_REQUEST['destination'] = $dest;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function MY_MODULE_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  global $user;
  switch ($op) {
    case 'logout':
      drupal_goto('user');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: replace 'stat' to 'YORMODELENAME'

Comment: Be sure to set the weight for your module to be very heavy (9999) or something so it runs very late in the request cycle. Otherwise you risk some module that SHOULD be running during the logout request not actually running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with Rules instead of code.

But if it is not working, there may be a drupal_goto() interfering elsewhere.

You should also put in a watchdog call inside of the logout case to know that your hook fired.

Comment: Doesn't look like the logout case is ever fired.

Comment: Where would drupal_goto be interfering on a fresh site with no other modules enabled?

Comment: Can you put a debug statement in and see what the $op is when you logout? Is the case really 'logout'? I remember having trouble with this hook before, but Rules works for redirecting on login/logout.

Comment: Just occurred to me, it won't fire at all if the module hook is named wrong. Check on that?

Comment: I'm just using a generic redirect_user for the hook.  If I just leave the login case, it works fine, so I think the module is at least setup correctly.  Watchdog doesn't record anything even when leaving the call outside of the switch, and I can't get any generic output printed.  Is there a better way to return the contents of $op for testing?